# A question about the verb « lier »

Tags: verbes

**(a)** “The doctor is linking my dad’s persistent cough **to** his smoking”.

**(b)** “The doctor is linking my dad’s persistant cough **with** his smoking”.

Sentences **(a)** and **(b)** equal each other.

For **(a)**, I’ve happily arrived at « La docteur lie la toux persistante de mon père à son tabac. »

But for **(b)**, is *« La docteur lie la toux persistante de mon père **avec** son tabac. »* grammatically correct? If no, should the word **avec** be substituted for **à** here?

My level is beginner therefore please please please keep all explanations as simple as possible. Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Lier la toux de mon père avec son tabac* doesn't work well.

"*Lier à* sth" means "link to something" but "*lier avec* sth" usually means "tie using something"

Thus your sentence might be understood to something like "the doctor tied my father's cough with his tobacco".

I'd rather say:

- *Le médecin lie* (or *relie*, *associe* or *corrèle*) *la toux persistante de mon père à son tabagisme.*
- *Le médecin fait un lien entre la toux persistante de mon père et son tabagisme.*

or simply:

- *Le médecin lie la toux persistante de mon père au tabac.*

Comment: À noter qu'il existe un mot pour signifier le fait de fumer du tabac : le tabagisme.

Comment: @LaurentS. C'est vrai, merci !

Comment: Thank you so much for this helpful explanation @jlliagre ! 

Answer (score 1):

"La docteur lie la toux persistante de mon père à son tabac." can be understood without ambiguity but it is not good French. There are two problems.

It is not the tobacco itself that is the cause of bad health but the *use* that is made of it (It is clear that you can use a little tobacco and keep in good health.)

The verb "lier" in this context is not proper. In its figurative meaning it signifies "to constitute a tie" not "to discern that there is a tie", or said differently "find that there is a tie"".

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lier)) II. − Au fig.
> A. − Lier qqc. à qqc., lier deux ou plusieurs choses entre elles. Associer étroitement, mettre ensemble, réunir par un rapport logique ou nécessaire, par une relation de ressemblance, de continuité, de dépendance. Synon. **attacher, rattacher, coordonner, conjuguer, faire dépendre**.

The discussion about which preposition to use is not relevant because the verb is not proper; however the two prépositions, "à" and "avec" are used with "lier", although the meanings are different.

There are several options.

- La doctoresse **explique** la toux persistante de mon père **par son usage du** tabac.
- La doctoresse **explique** la toux persistante de mon père **par** le/son tabagisme.
- La doctoresse **dit que** la toux persistante de mon père **est due** [au]/[à son] tabagisme.
- La doctoresse **dit que** le/son tabagisme est **responsable/la cause/la raison** de la toux persistante de mon père.
- La doctoresse **identifie** le/son tabagisme comme (étant) **responsable/la cause/la raison** de la toux persistante de mon père.

Comment: Thank you for this insight @LPH !  Just to confirm, when you say “This verb “lier” in this context is not proper”, do you mean that in this scenario this is the incorrect verb to use?

Comment: Sorry to bother you @LPH  but I still don’t understand why **lier** is the wrong verb to use :/ It clear states in the definition you gave that the definition of **lier qqc à qch** is **« unir par un rapport logique »**. So in my sentence, the doctor, using logic, linked the dad’s persistent cough to *tabagisme*. So it should be **« La docteur lie la toux persistante de mon père avec son tabagisme. »**, right?

Comment: @CubbyKushi I couldn't answer sooner as they suspended my account for 7 days. I asked them to do something about making you know but they probably did nothing. Yes, that is what I mean: this is why I emphasized the synonyms (attacher, rattacher, coordonner, conjuguer, faire dépendre). "Lier A à B" does not have the sense of "voir une connexion entre A et B", which is approximately what "link A to B" means. (1/2)

Comment: The difference is explained as follows (if I get this right):  there is a shift from "unir" as being an entity (abstract) that binds to "unir" as _seeing_, _perceiving_ such a binding entity (that is what obtains in English, but I believe not in French).  (2/2)

Answer (score 0):

J'approuve l'explication de LPH sur l'usage du verbe "lier" dans la phrase en question. Cependant, je pense qu'il n'a pas indiqué le verbe qui convient le mieux pour cette traduction, il s'agit à mon sens du verbe "*attribuer*": En bon français, on dirait donc:

*"Le docteur attribue la toux persistante de mon père à son tabagisme"*

Comment: Oui, la phrase est bien meilleure. On peut juste lui reprocher d'aller un peu plus loin dans le diagnostic que la phrase originale. On ne pourrait pas dire qu'on attribue le tabagisme du père à sa toux persistante ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Il aurait probablement fallu plus d'explications en question. Est-ce que c'est _spécule sur le lien_, _évoque comme facteur contributoire_, ou _explique par_ ? On ne le dit pas. Ce genre de scénario se produit assez souvent et on est enlignés par la question alors que sa prémisse pourrait s'avérer inexacte.